# Bootstrap - internal link in modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In twitter bootstrap, I have a modal with two columns: one with a nav-bar with diferent items and the other with a "scrollable" div with a lot of text.

What I want to do:

1. Be able to navigate in the modal(between different items) without having the background moving
2. Have a "smooth navigation" with a javascript snippet, so that the page "flows" from one anchor point to the other in 0.2 sec.

For point 1, I user href ="#id" in my navbar, which works, but the problem is that my background is moving to the bottom of the document when I am doing that, which I want to avoid.

For point 2, the snippet I use to have the "smooth navigation" does not work in the modal. Do you now a snippet that works even in modals?

It is hard to show it in a fiddle, so it is probabaly better that you go and check out the end result immediately. Go on link> click on "get started" > hover picture on the left> click on "more"> try to navigate in the modal and you will see that the background moves to the bottom of the page when clicking on for instance "empower women": [link disabled]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some code or a fiddle that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I edited. Let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd scroll it with JavaScript/JQuery instead of the hrefs.

Given this function:

```
function scroller(scrollMe, scrollTo){
    scrollMe.animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo.position().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

Call it from the link click as:

```
scroller($('.div-project-description'), $('#empower'));
```